# terraform Error: host for provisioner cannot be empty azurerm

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

here is my config
I have to add all the configurations in one file

I have the part of config not related to the issue and keep the part that most important to understand the issue

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}




# Create public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "myterraformpublicip" {
  name                = "myPublicIP"
  location            = "eastus"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"

  tags = {
    environment = "Terraform Demo"
  }
}

#create a data to recicve ip
data "azurerm_public_ip" "myterraformpublicip" {
  name                = azurerm_public_ip.myterraformpublicip.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name

}

output "vm_ip" {
  value = data.azurerm_public_ip.myterraformpublicip.ip_address
}

# Create (and display) an SSH key
resource "tls_private_key" "example_ssh" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}
output "tls_private_key" {
  value     = tls_private_key.example_ssh.private_key_pem
  sensitive = true
}

# Create virtual machine
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "myterraformvm" {
  name                  = "myVM"
  location              = "eastus"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.myterraformnic.id]
  size                  = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  os_disk {
    name                 = "myOsDisk"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "18.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  computer_name                   = "myvm"
  admin_username                  = "azureuser"
  disable_password_authentication = true

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "azureuser"
    public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
  }

  boot_diagnostics {
    storage_account_uri = azurerm_storage_account.mystorageaccount.primary_blob_endpoint
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "Terraform Demo"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "nginx" {
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo yum install nginx -y",
      "sudo service nginx start",
      "sudo rm /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html",
      "echo '<html><head><title>Blue Team Server</title></head><body style=\"background-color:#1F778D\"><p style=\"text-align: center;\"><span style=\"color:#FFFFFF;\"><span style=\"font-size:28px;\">Blue Team</span></span></p></body></html>' | sudo tee /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"
    ]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      host        = data.azurerm_public_ip.myterraformpublicip.ip_address
      user        = "azureuser"
      private_key = tls_private_key.example_ssh.private_key_pem
      timeout     = "1m"
    }
  }
}
```

I still get the same error after many trials I am a beginner level with terraform and need help, Note: if I apply again the ssh connection to the previous public IP.

Comment: I have changed the public IP allocation_method   = "Static" and now get a new error  timeout - last error: SSH authentication failed (azureuser@xx.xx.xx.xx): ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods 
[none publickey], no supported methods remain

Comment: it's work fine if I run ssh from a terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the on disk public key at `file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")` when bootstrapping the instance.

Then you are using a mismatching key `tls_private_key.example_ssh.private_key_pem` in your remote-exec provisioner.

Using `tls_private_key` is not recommended as it is stores the private key in plain text in your terraform state. Rather use the public key stored on disk.

The below will work and is more secure:

```
resource "null_resource" "nginx" {
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo yum install nginx -y",
      "sudo service nginx start",
      "sudo rm /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html",
      "echo '<html><head><title>Blue Team Server</title></head><body style=\"background-color:#1F778D\"><p style=\"text-align: center;\"><span style=\"color:#FFFFFF;\"><span style=\"font-size:28px;\">Blue Team</span></span></p></body></html>' | sudo tee /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"
    ]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      host        = data.azurerm_public_ip.myterraformpublicip.ip_address
      user        = "azureuser"
      private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
      timeout     = "1m"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot It's work now but have you any idea why when I have used the public IP allocation_method = "Dynamic" I get the error host for provisioner cannot be empty azurerm

Comment: No, this is not a correct use case. Rather than using a null_resource consider custom_data in the azurerm_linux_virtual_machine resouce block. Good example here - https://sbulav.github.io/terraform/terraform-azurerm-compute-custom-data/